# Questions about the error in quadrature formulas

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, simpsons-rule

everyone, I am new to these subjects and I would like to clarify a subject that is little covered in my textbook.

It tells me that fixed an n, a number of sub-intervals to use to calculate the integral using the composite trapezoidal or Simpson rule, we can calculate the error for $E_n$ and $E_{2n}$ that is relative to the same integral considering the n sub-intervals and 2n sub-intervals. In this way we can obtain a more accurate estimate of the error, it says. Could someone explain me better what is meant? And especially if I do $E_n/E_{2n}$, what information do I get?

Comment: Please do look up "Richardson extrapolation" and report back if this answers your question. The advanced topic is then "Romberg integration".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the trapezoidal rule with $N=n, 2n, 4n$ segments, then you get a value

$$
I_N = I_* + c_2 N^{-2} + c_4 N^{-4} + ...
$$
The estimation of the terms of this expansion from two or more numerical evaluations for different $N$ is called Richardson extrapolation or Romberg integration (successively eliminating the terms for $n^{-2k}$).

Now if you compute the error from two integrations for $N=n,2n$ by eliminating the exact value $I_*$, you get
$$
I_n-I_{2n}=c_2n^{-2}(1-2^{-2})+c_4n^{-4}(1-2^{-4})+
$$
so that you get the error estimate
$$
E_n=\frac43(I_n-I_{2n}) = c_2n^{-2} + \frac54 c_4n^{-4}+...
$$

If you now compute
$$
\frac{E_n}{E_{2n}}
=\frac{c_2 + \frac54 c_4n^{-2}+...}{c_22^{-2} + \frac54 c_42^{-4}n^{-2}+...}
=4+\frac{\frac{15}{4}c_4n^{-2}+...}{c_2+\frac5{16}c_4n^{-2}+...}
$$
you can see from the numerical value of this fraction that if it is far away from $4$ that with some high probability there is some error in the implementation.

If you compute a series of these fractions, you should find some middle region of values for $n$ where the quotient is close to $4$. For large values of $n$ one has to add the floating point noise of size $\mu\cdot n$ to the error, it will dominate the error for $n>1/\sqrt[3]\mu\sim 10^5$, where $\mu=2^{-52}\sim 10^{-16}$ is the machine constant of the floating point data type. Thus for large $n$ the error will increase again in a vaguely linear way and the quotient will fluctuate randomly.

If such a middle region does not exist, then the coefficient $c_4$ or a higher one is very large against $c_2$, the function is then either rapidly growing or highly oscillatory and you will need more adapted methods.

---

See also similar observations in [a BDF ODE solver](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3503013/115115), [a fourth order Taylor ODE solver](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2953714/115115), [classical RK4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3235360/115115), and [one-sided and](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2488893/115115) [symmetric and further improved difference quotients](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2019715/115115).

Comment: I didn't understand one thing. In general, should the fraction be a value close to 4? If so, should I get a value around 15 for Simpson's method? And if I get (from Simpson) 1 because the estimates used in the ratio are the same number?

Comment: Simpson is Richardson extrapolation from trapezoidal, eliminating the $c_2n^{-2}$ term. As the leading error term is then $\tilde c_4n^{-4}$, the quotient should be $2^4=16$. However, the influence of the floating point noise starts here already at $n\sim 1/\sqrt[5]\mu\simeq 10^3$ (approximately, deviations by a factor of $10$ are possible).

Comment: Yeah, I meant 16. A typo... So I shouldn't worry if for very high n values, the error ratio with Simpson's method gives me values close to 1?

Comment: Yes. If you want to extend the experiment to those higher $n$ values, you need a correspondingly smaller $\mu$, that is, you need to perform all computations including the function evaluation using a multi-precision data type.

Comment: Sorry if I reopen the discussion, but doing some tests I noticed that I didn't understand very well what information we get from the ratio of the two errors and what it means if I get values much smaller than 4 or 16 depending on the method.

Comment: The ration of the errors is $2^p$ or close to it, where $p$ is the order of the method. You get ratios that are smaller than that if $E_{2n}$ is dominated by floating point errors. It means that you have left the working range of this combination of numerical method, function and data type.

Comment: Oh, thanks, now I get it. Just one more question: what difference does it make considering log2 of that relationship rather than having the value of the relationship itself?

Comment: You get the order estimate directly. Nice but nothing really new.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification